# Selenium script freezes trying to write into an iframe in the Shopify Product Add interface

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm writing a Selenium script to automate filling a Shopify product list. At one point, I have to enter a description into an iframe within the html. I'm not sure why, but when it tries to activate the iframe, the wait conditions do not trigger, and the browser just freezes, without the script breaking away. When I mouse over the browser, the pointer is stuck in the little "hand" that signals clicking a hyperlink. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

from dbase import get_vars, database_path, sheet_name, vendor_checkbox, login_, pw_
from LoginStart import Login
# from Pegador2 import inums
from commons.navigation import new_tab_

(...)

for index, row in dataframe.iloc[1:].iterrows():

(...)

    # Click the thingy that switches to html
    pshowhtml = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Show HTML"]')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Show HTML"]')))
    pshowhtml.click()

    # Activate the iframe for the Description and send it
    desc_iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'product-description_ifr')
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'product-description_ifr')))
    # driver.switch_to.frame(desc_iframe)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tinymce')))  # The freeze occurs around here
    product_description_iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tinymce')
    product_description_iframe.send_keys(row[2])
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    # Click it again
    pshowhtml = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Show editor"]')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Show editor"]')))
    pshowhtml.click()

(...)
```

And this is the html from Shopify that I'm trying to work on (Sorry about the sloppy formatting, I tried to copy it via Inspector but it didn't cooperate much):

```html
<div id="product-description_parent">

<div id="product-description_iframecontainer">

<iframe id="product-description_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" src="javascript:&quot;&quot;" style="width: 100%; height: 168px; display: block; min-height: 150px;">

<!DOCTYPE html><html style="overflow-y: hidden;">

<head><style id="mceDefaultStyles" type="text/css">
p {
margin-top: 0;
}

html, body {
cursor: text;
}

html {
font-size: 100%;
}

body {
overflow-x: hidden;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, San Francisco, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
font-size: 0.875rem; /* Maps to var(--p-font-size-100) */
line-height: 1.4;
color: #1f2124; /* Maps to var(--p-color-text) */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
margin: 0.6rem 0.75rem;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 40em) {
body {
font-size: 1rem;
}
}

/* The body y margin of 0.66rem works well for type, but is too tight for solid elements. Push them down a bit. */
body > img:first-child,
body > iframe:first-child {
margin-top: .15rem;
}

h1 {
line-height: 1.2;
}

h1 {
margin: 0 0 .75rem;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0 0 .66rem 0;
}

p, img, iframe {
margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

p > img,
p > iframe {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

body > *:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px dashed #CCC;
}

body {
min-height: 150px;
}

.mce-content-body div.mce-resizehandle {position: absolute;border: 1px solid black;box-sizing: box-sizing;background: #FFF;width: 7px;height: 7px;z-index: 10000}.mce-content-body .mce-resizehandle:hover {background: #000}.mce-content-body img[data-mce-selected],.mce-content-body hr[data-mce-selected] {outline: 1px solid black;resize: none}.mce-content-body .mce-clonedresizable {position: absolute;outline: 1px dashed black;opacity: .5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);z-index: 10000}.mce-content-body .mce-resize-helper {background: #555;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);border-radius: 3px;border: 1px;color: white;display: none;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 12px;white-space: nowrap;line-height: 14px;margin: 5px 10px;padding: 5px;position: absolute;z-index: 10001}
.mce-visual-caret {position: absolute;background-color: black;background-color: currentcolor;}.mce-visual-caret-hidden {display: none;}*[data-mce-caret] {position: absolute;left: -1000px;right: auto;top: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.mce-content-body .mce-offscreen-selection {position: absolute;left: -9999999999px;max-width: 1000000px;}.mce-content-body *[contentEditable=false] {cursor: default;}.mce-content-body *[contentEditable=true] {cursor: text;}
</style><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>



<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="product-description" contenteditable="true" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-mce-style="overflow-y: auto; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1117.0" data-gr-ext-installed="" data-new-gr-c-s-loaded="14.1117.0" spellcheck="false"><p><span data-sanitized-data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" style="text-decoration: underline;">&lt;div id="product-description_parent"&gt;</span></p><p><span data-sanitized-data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" style="text-decoration: underline;">&lt;div id="product-description_iframecontainer"&gt;</span></p><p><span data-sanitized-data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" style="text-decoration: underline;">&lt;iframe id="product-description_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" src="javascript:&amp;quot;&amp;quot;" style="width: 100%; height: 168px; display: block; min-height: 150px;"&gt;</span></p><p><span data-sanitized-data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" style="text-decoration: underline;"><br data-sanitized-data-mce-bogus="1" data-mce-bogus="1"></span></p><p><span data-sanitized-data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;" style="text-decoration: underline;">&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span><!----></p></body><grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration></html>

</iframe></div></div>
```

Finally, this is the error code I get after I finally interrupt the script:

```
Under Armour Men's Armour Fleece Hoodie (Black)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\jon\jonMain.py", line 56, in <module>
    product_description_iframe.send_keys(row[2])
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 438, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 290, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 311, in _request
    response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\OneDrive\Documents\Code\py\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\fvckr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 954, in close
    def close(self):

KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Sorry in advance for any errors I may be making in posting this question. This is my first time writing a serious programming related question and I barely started learning on my own a few months ago. Thanks for your attention.

I have tried modifying the wait conditions and changing the selector in the line

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tinymce')))
```

for example, using By.TAGNAME, 'body'
But it doesn't help. The thing that weirds me out the most is that the script can outright freeze even with waits.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the script didn't actually froze, it just was unspeakably slow. The method I was using to populate the  within the iframe was

```
    product_description_iframe.**send_keys**(row[2])
```

Which is too slow. I solved this issue by populating that field with a small Javascript line:

```
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1];", product_description_iframe, row[2])
```

This basically changes the value instantly to what I need it to be. Hope this helps!